# How to add onclick listeners to elements auto generated by gatsby-transformer-remark?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using Gatsby.js with plugins `gatsby-transformer-remark` to display markdown files as pages, as described in [the official docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/).

It works great, but I am looking for a way to add onclick listener to all the footnote links that are converted from markdown.

Currently, `gatsby-transformer-remark` generates this kind of HTML below.

```
// markdown
some long text. [^1]
...
[^1]: footnote description
```

```
// html generated by 'gatsby-transformer-remark'

<p>some long text. 
  <sup id="fnref-1">
    <a href="#fn-1" class="footnote-ref">1</a>
  </sup>
</p>

...

<ol>
  <li id="fn-1">
    <p>footnote description</p>
    <a href="#fnref-1" class="footnote-backref">↩</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
<p>some long text. 
  <sup id="fnref-1">
    <a href="#fn-1" onclick="displayModal();" class="footnote-ref">1</a>
  </sup>
</p>

...

<ol>
  <li id="fn-1">
    <p>footnote description</p>
    <a href="#fnref-1" class="footnote-backref">↩</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Did you see this plugin? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-component/

Comment: @ksav thanks, I checked it, however I didn't think using the plugin is the best way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add this function by

`footerElement.addEventListener("click", this.someFunc);`.

However there is a more elegant way to do this.